# How to set oidc ResponseType to get both claims and access_token?

Tags: oauth, openid, identityserver4, openid-connect

Recently I am working on an SSO with IdentityServer4, when I debug the code, I found that the ResponseType setting cause a tricky problem.
When I set My Client like this:

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                options.Authority = Configuration["Auth:IdentityServer"];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ClientId = Configuration["Auth:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Auth:ClientSecret"];
                options.ResponseType = "id_token";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                //options.Scope.Add("8e6144b5-87f6-4638-bf08-1a64599a8b39");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            });
```

I can get claims like this(with full claim list):
[image]
But when I change the responseType like this `options.ResponseType = "id_token token";`
The claims is like this(only a little claims issued):

[image]

If I want both full claim list and access token when user log in, what should I do to get both of them?

Comment: You have ```options.ResponseType = "id_token token"``` for the client defined above and as your desired setting. Did you mean to change one of them to a different value?

Comment: Sorry, yes I changed from "id_token" to "id_token token" then I get less claims than before.After checking the identity server, I find the claims are well issued but not received by client side.

Answer (score 1):

By default, IdentityServer will not provide user claims in the identity token if an access token is requested along with it. You can see this happening in the source code [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/63a50d7838af25896fbf836ea4e4f37b5e179cd8/src/ResponseHandling/Default/AuthorizeResponseGenerator.cs#L171).
To make sure the identity token always contains the user claims (whether an access token is requested with it or not) is to set [`AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken`](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/client.html?highlight=AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken) to `true` on your client.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to use one of the examples from the documentation. Correct me if I'm wrong.

If not then - change your flow to Hybrid (which means `ResponseType = "code id_token token"`). Do that on the identity server side too. To the scopes add also `openid` and `profile`. And then, where you list your claims, you can use (assuming that you are using the razor page to list them):

```
@foreach (var claim in ((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal)User).Claims)
{
    <li>@claim.Type : @claim.Value</li>
}
```

This should list all the claims you have (including the access_token itself).

Comment: Hi, It works for me when using "id_token" as response type. when I change the response type to "id_token token", claims disappears then access_token appears.....I really confuse why it happens...

Comment: @Ternence.Lin - now I see your problem. Well the claims are in there. They are just encoded in the `access_token`. Try decoding it in `jwt.io` and you will see them. One more thing - did you try adding the lines I showed you in your page?